# What is meaning of "really pisses people of"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

I need a [simple English version](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_English_Wikipedia) to understand [the very short original text](http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?p=644493#p644493)

> @op: ok, you were right. now did you really have to start a dozen threads in many different forums for that? no. and that is the very thing that really pisses people of, to the point where your actual problem does not matter anymore.

thanks.

Comment: It's a typo.  "really pisses people off", as in makes them angry.

Comment: While *pissed off* always means irritated/upset/angry, *pissed* alone is sometimes used identically and sometimes to mean inebriated. From a casual reading of several discussion sites online, I conclude that it's not accurate to attribute the former meaning just to North America and the latter just to the UK.

Comment: @RonaldSole "pissed" to mean "drunk" is purely BrE. In AmE it means "upset", as in "Dude, why you are so pissed?"

Comment: @Andrew I've lived in Africa and Australia as well as North America and the UK; it's not just conventions in the latter two that matter. See https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/937/pissed-vs-pissed-off

Comment: @RonaldSole understood.  It's just for the sake of simplicity on ELL I talk about BrE usage vs. AmE usage.  "Pissed" is also AusE usage, and perhaps similar in South Africa, India, and other places where their English is closer to British than American.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In simple English:

> You are correct. However, you made people very angry. People are angry because you asked the same question many times in many places. People are angry enough that your question is no longer important to them.